# Use IOS SDK 13 in XCode 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new in IOS development and probably my question is stupid but is it possible to build IOS app in XCode 9.2 with IOS SDK 13? I'm on Catalina 10.12.6? Or I need move to XCode 11 which supplied with SDK 13 already?

Comment: You need Xcode 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to build app for iOS 13 in Xcode 9.2. You need Xcode 11 or above. You can download latest Xcode from App Store [link](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) .

Comment: To get XCode 11 I need to update MacOS to Catalina but it cannot be installed on my IMac because it assembled in Mid 2011. It is very stupid!